# Getting location from meta data on iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, cllocationmanager, geotagging

Is there a way to get the location out of a newly taken image, without using the CLLocationManager?

Its kind of stupid to use a location manager if you can just extract the data out of the image.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use iphone-exif: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/

```
#import "EXFJpeg.h"

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
    NSLog(@"image picked %@ with info %@", image, editingInfo);
    NSData* jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation (image,0.5);
    EXFJpeg* jpegScanner = [[EXFJpeg alloc] init];
    [jpegScanner scanImageData: jpegData];
    EXFMetaData* exifData = jpegScanner.exifMetaData;
    EXFJFIF* jfif = jpegScanner.jfif;
    EXFTag* tagDefinition = [exifData tagDefinition: [NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_DateTime]];
    //EXFTag* latitudeDef = [exifData tagDefinition: [NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_GPSLatitude]];
    //EXFTag* longitudeDef = [exifData tagDefinition: [NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_GPSLongitude]];
    id latitudeValue = [exifData tagValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_GPSLatitude]];
    id longitudeValue = [exifData tagValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_GPSLongitude]];
    id datetime = [exifData tagValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_DateTime]];
    id t = [exifData tagValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:EXIF_Model]];
....
....
```